# MySQL utility "mysqldiff": Database name difference alone?

Tags: mysql, difference, utility

I used to use Adam Spiers' mysqldiff tool, but it hasn't been maintained in many years, so on a new server I'm trying the mysql-utilities package, which contains a similar tool. But even when I compare two databases that have the exact same schema, the fact that their names are different (duh!) is enough to make the tool say the compare failed (which seems an awfully strong word for finding differences, but I guess that's how it works). Here is the output:

```
[root](22:05:48)[~]$ mysqldiff --server1=root:mypassword@localhost kizuna_master:kizuna_misa
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Comparing `kizuna_master` to `kizuna_misa`                       [FAIL]
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- `kizuna_master`
+++ `kizuna_misa`
@@ -1 +1 @@
-CREATE DATABASE `kizuna_master` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
+CREATE DATABASE `kizuna_misa` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
Compare failed. One or more differences found.
```

In that case, it would ALWAYS fail if comparing two databases on the same server - that doesn't make sense. Am I doing something wrong?

---

**EDIT:** By Solarflare's suggestion, I also tried mysqldbcompare:
`mysqldbcompare --skip-row-count --skip-data-check --run-all-tests --server1=root:mypassword@localhost kizuna_master:kizuna_dev`

But it's result is the same as mysqldiff but wordier. And with both commands, not only does it fail on the `CREATE DATABASE` definition, but it also fails on all tables that have an auto-incremented key field! Good grief - if I'm saying I don't want to compare the data (--skip-data-check), why does it think I would want it to fail just because of `AUTO_INCREMENT`? Here is the first part of the output of the above `mysqldbcompare` call:

```
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Checking databases kizuna_master and kizuna_dev on server1
#
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- `kizuna_master`
+++ `kizuna_dev`
@@ -1 +1 @@
-CREATE DATABASE `kizuna_master` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
+CREATE DATABASE `kizuna_dev` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */

#                                                   Defn    Row     Data
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TABLE     action                                  FAIL    SKIP    SKIP
#
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- `kizuna_master`.`action`
+++ `kizuna_dev`.`action`
@@ -9,4 +9,4 @@
   KEY `PersonID` (`PersonID`),
   KEY `ContactTypeID` (`ActionTypeID`),
   CONSTRAINT `action_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ActionTypeID`) REFERENCES `actiontype` (`ActionTypeID`)
-) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1953 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

# TABLE     actiontype                              FAIL    SKIP    SKIP
#
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- `kizuna_master`.`actiontype`
+++ `kizuna_dev`.`actiontype`
@@ -4,4 +4,4 @@
   `BGColor` char(6) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'FFFFFF',
   `Template` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`ActionTypeID`)
-) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

# TABLE     addrprint                               pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     attendance                              pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     category                                FAIL    SKIP    SKIP
#
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- `kizuna_master`.`category`
+++ `kizuna_dev`.`category`
@@ -4,4 +4,4 @@
   `UseFor` enum('OP','P','O') CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OP' COMMENT 'Whether the category can be used for people, orgs,
 or both',
   PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`),
   KEY `Category` (`Category`)
-) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Etc... The whole thing is like that.

---

**EDIT #2:** Adding `--skip-table-options` got it to be quiet about the auto-increment, although I don't know what other differences that option will ignore and whether I care. But although it still reports the database name difference, it doesn't use the word "fail" anymore, so I guess that is an improvement. Here is the output of `mysqldbcompare --skip-row-count --skip-data-check --run-all-tests --skip-table-options --difftype=differ --server1=root:mypassword@localhost kizuna_master:kizuna_dev`:

```
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# Checking databases kizuna_master and kizuna_dev on server1
#
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

- CREATE DATABASE `kizuna_master` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
?                         ^^^^ ^
+ CREATE DATABASE `kizuna_dev` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
?                         ^ ^

#                                                   Defn    Row     Data
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TABLE     action                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     actiontype                              pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     addrprint                               pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     attendance                              pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     category                                pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     config                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     custom                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     donation                                pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     donationtype                            pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     event                                   pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     household                               pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     labelprint                              pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     loginlog                                pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     output                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     outputset                               pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     percat                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     perorg                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     person                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     photoprint                              pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     pledge                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     postalcode                              pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     preselect                               pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     upload                                  pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     uploadtype                              pass    SKIP    SKIP
# TABLE     user                                    pass    SKIP    SKIP

# Databases are consistent given skip options specified.
#
# ...done
```

So I guess in my bash script I could pipe that into grep and check for the word "fail". But what a mess - the old `mysqldiff` tool was so simple and clear.

One other question was about the tool version. `mysqldiff --help` says: "MySQL Utilities mysqldiff version 1.3.6 (part of MySQL Workbench Distribution 5.2.47)". I initially downloaded the newest one directly, but it wouldn't install - this is what yum can give me on CentOS7. My database is MariaDB 10.2.8, if that matters. (It was 10.2.4 when I started this discussion, but I updated since then.)

Comment: Have your tried to `--force` option? While it will not remove the databasename to be reported as different (well, it is), it will continue to search for other differences, which might be your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks, that helps for the situation where there really are other differences (although I would rather not see it spew all the stuff that "passes" but just show me the differences). But I want to use this in a bash script (the script only needs pass/fail, not the details), and as long as the name is different (which it will always be), my script will not be able to tell that the schemas are identical, unless I do some sort of complex parsing of the output.

Comment: With `--force`, you could use the line count as an indicator of failure instead of the text/status. If your databases are completely identical, you could also try `mysqldbcompare` (with `--skip-data-check`) which is also in the utility pack (and uses `mysqldiff` internally, but will skip the database name).

Comment: How do you get `mysqldbcompare` to skip the database name? It always includes it for me. My best guess at appropriate options was `--skip-row-count --skip-data-check --run-all-tests` - is there something else I need?

Comment: @Solarflare I forgot to include your username in my latest comment, so you probably weren't aware that I wrote again. See above - if `mysqldbcompare` can skip the database name, I'd like to know how to do that.

Comment: It's the default behaviour, you should not have to do anything. What do you get as a result? (It will *just* ignore a different name, nothing else, e.g. a different default charset - although your sample showed that the options are the same).

Comment: @Solarflare I've added to my question to show the result you asked for.

Comment: You can skip the autoincrement by using `--skip-table-options` (although it will skip different engines too then). Not sure why it will you get troubles with the database name. It works for me, and also the documentation explicitly states it will ignore the name difference. Maybe try the option `--difftype=differ`, it will mark the exact positions that are different, maybe there is something else we are not seeing. Also check if you have a current version of the tool. Otherwise I am out of ideas (apart from maybe debugging the script). You might also simply remove the test from the script.

Comment: @Solarflare Take a look at my edit #2 above - I'm curious to hear whether yours gives that kind of output, where it reports the difference in the database name without using the word "fail" (once enough options are added to prevent any other complaints). Is yours completely silent about the name?

Comment: I tested version 1.3.6. It seems not to work with full group by-mode. Apart from that, it doesn't hide the database name difference, so that explains it. You should have mentioned that earlier! It also does not really make sense to not use adams script (last update 1 year ago), and instead switch to a 4 year old version of the mysql utilities. Anyway, these are just python scripts, so extracting and running version 1.6 should work, not sure why your install failed. `--skip-table-options` does ignore every option (engine, charset, ...). To scrape, you could look for "Databases are consistent".

Comment: And yes, 1.6.5 does give the same output, including the "Databases are consistent", but it will in addition hide the name difference. But both versions do not treat them as an error. As mentioned before, I was not able to run 1.3 with `only_full_group_by`-mode enabled, this is something you might want to consider, although I didn't investigate it further than to unset that option to get it do run, so it might work for you.

Comment: @Solarflare I know SO is going to start complaining that our comment conversation is too long, but... ;) I tried to install Adam's script, but I lost a wrestling match with CPAN - it says I don't have write permission for the Perl library directories, in spite of being root! When looking for clues about that, I found a place where Adam said he has abandoned his tool and recommended using the MySQL utility instead. I had no idea the version that yum is willing to install is that old. I'll have to do some research about how to install Python scripts - I don't use Python.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem but found a solution. Both mysqldiff and mysqldbcompare come from mysql-utilities, so share the same code base.

In my case I need to run laravel migrations on databases which *should* have the same structure but not the same name. When I run `mysqldbcompare --version` it shows

> MySQL Utilities mysqldbcompare version 1.6.1
>
> License type: GPLv2

Now, just like you, I tried to check for database structures with
`mysqldbcompare --server1={server1} --server2={server1} --difftype=sql --skip-row-count --skip-data-check --run-all-tests --skip-table-options --changes-for=server2 {db1}:{db2}`

on a stock ubuntu 16.04, mysqldbcompare raises the same error, complaining about the different database name:

```
# WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# server2 on localhost: ... connected.
# Checking databases backend_21 on server1 and backend_1 on server2
#

# WARNING: Cannot generate SQL statements for these objects.
# Check the difference output for other discrepencies.
--- `backend_21`
+++ `backend_1`
@@ -1 +1 @@
-CREATE DATABASE `backend_21` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
+CREATE DATABASE `backend_1` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
# WARNING: Could not generate SQL statements for differences between `backend_21` and `backend_1`. No changes required or not supported difference.

# WARNING: Cannot generate SQL statements for these objects.
# Check the difference output for other discrepencies.
--- `backend_21`
+++ `backend_1`
@@ -1 +1 @@
-CREATE DATABASE `backend_21` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */
+CREATE DATABASE `backend_1` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci */

#                                                   Defn    Row     Data
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TABLE     bot_bus_connections                     pass    SKIP    SKIP
...
# TABLE     user_settings                           pass    SKIP    SKIP

# Databases are consistent given skip options specified.
#
# ...done
```

After some investigation, I found that this behavior is an already **reported bug** and got **fixed in version 1.6.4**: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77058.

So after manually upgrading of those python files, I now run `mysqldbcompare --version` with

> MySQL Utilities mysqldbcompare version 1.6.4
>
> License type: GPLv2

And the result is as expected:

```
# WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# server2 on localhost: ... connected.
# Checking databases backend_21 on server1 and backend_1 on server2
#
#                                                   Defn    Row     Data
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TABLE     bot_bus_connections                     pass    SKIP    SKIP
...
# TABLE     user_settings                           pass    SKIP    SKIP

# Databases are consistent given skip options specified.
#
# ...done
```

There is, however, still one annoying thing and that is ignored `CREATE TABLE` statements. So, if there are new tables in database1 (my sort of template database) it just throws a warning like so:

```
# WARNING: Objects in server1.backend_1 but not in server1.backend_2:
# TABLE: statistic_chats
# TABLE: localizations
# TABLE: statistic_customers
```

Which is also already reported since 2015, yet no reaction of mysql so far. My kinda dirty solution is

1. to search for this string and
2. run fake `CREATE TABLE` statements, so the tables are present and
3. re-run the migration which fixes the fake tables with the actually structure

Hope that helps.

Cheers